# Is it possible for the plot of Falling Down to happen in a single day?

Tags: realism, falling-down

I was watching "Falling Down" (1993). Its clear that the plot is intended to happen on a single day, because it is the last day for Sergeant Martin Prendergast.

So first of all Sergeant Martin Prendergast rejects the Korean guy's complaints on shop damage done by William "D-Dens" Foster. "D-Fens" beats gangland guys with a baseball bat etc. He later realizes that the crimes are all done by the same person.

**Is it possible for the plot of *Falling Down* to happen in a single day?**

Comment: I have tried to rephrase your question to the only possible question I could image you to be asking. If that is not your actual question, though, I'm afraid it's just unclear what you're really asking.

Comment: So you are just asking if the plot of the movie could happen in a single day? But isn't this exactly what you already noticed in the first sentence? The film's plot obviously happens on a single day, as you say yourself, so of course it's possible. What is it that is unclear about it to you?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [**FallingDownFilm.com**](http://fallingdownfilm.com/category/production-information/)

> The July 1993 issue of the British magazine Empire had several in-depth articles on Falling Down, including one piece that commented on why the film was “geographically unsound,” ...
>
> > **“You Can’t Do That!” (p. 18)**
> >
> > “Surely D-Fens doesn’t expect to walk from Lincoln Heights in downtown L.A. to Venice Beach in one day?… Indeed, ‘D’ could have made it easier for himself if he hadn’t rather bizarrely insisted on machine-gunning a phone booth on the corner of Sunset Boulevard and Laurel Avenue—miles out of his way—and if he hadn’t decided to take a detour through snootsome Beverly Hills just to have a go at the richies. As the crow flies, it’s a 15-mile trip to Venice from Lincoln Heights, which is quite enough for one day’s walk—as D-Fens rampages, you’re looking at at least 25 miles.
> >
> > ‘Falling Down is not a documentary!,’ screams director Joel Schumacher when confronted with this geographical conundrum. ‘I don’t know how it is in London, but L.A. is sprawling, and if you go ten minutes in any direction it’s like you’re in a different world. So it’s like Michael is going through different cities in this movie—it’s not literally a walk through L.A.’

Essentially, given purely the distances involved it's too far for him to have walked in a single day but combined with the scenes inbetween where "D-Fens" isn't actually travelling it's unlikely that the journey could have been completed within the time period covered by the movie.